# Laravel 5 Eloquent chain query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I would like to get to know if this is well-formed chain query.

```
$users = Comment::first()->fromWebsite(2)->first()->ofUser(1)->first()->user()->first();
```

This is working but does not look like a nice piece of code. Can it be transformed somehow into a prettier or cleaner version? I know that it can have multiple new lines. Here is my Comment.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function website(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Website');
    }

    public function fromWebsite($websiteId){
        return $this->where('website_id', $websiteId);
    }

    public function ofUser($userId){
        return $this->where('user_id', $userId);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to get data of first user that wrote comment on website #2 and has user_id #1 and can I do this using cleaner code?

Comment: Well, first of all, you can get rid of the `first();` declarations by putting that into your model. But on the other hand, if you store website_id and user_id in the comment table, why are you passing id's into `fromWebsite($id)` and `ofUser($id);`. Couldn't you just do: `Comment::first()->user();`? You have to replace `$this->where('user_id', $userId)` with `$this->where('user_id', $userId)->first()`; The same goes for website though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you can see I am trying to get data of first user that wrote comment on website #2 and has user_id #1.

If this is your question, you could put everything in one call like this:

```
Comment::where('website_id', 2)->where('user_id', 1)->first();
```

If you'd like to make this even cleaner, you should write a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes), e.g.

```
function scopeFromUserForWebsite($query, $user_id, $website_id) {
    return $query->where('website_id', $user_id)->where('user_id', $website_id);
}
```

Having this you can simply use the following:

```
Comment::fromUserForWebsite(1,2)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, query scope is the way that seems to be perfect for me.